# Getting error parsing ProtoBuf data

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm serializing a linked list and when deserializing I get the following error.

`Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 'Protocol message had too many levels of nesting.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.SetRecursionLimit() to increase the depth limit.'`

I couldn't find a lot of documentation on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion limit can be set by using `CodedInputStream.CreateWithLimits`:

```
public static CodedInputStream CreateWithLimits(Stream input, int sizeLimit, int recursionLimit)
```

Note the default recursion is a depth of 64.  See the source [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/CodedInputStream.cs).

Edit:
Can you post your model for your linked list items?  You might be able to add in some flattening behavior before serialization is performed.